# Using Template Variables in CSS Classes in Vue JS 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I’m having trouble figuring out the best way to use variable returned by vue functions in CSS inline styles, in this case the “width” style.

I have 2 variables being returned to the template that I can use with the {{}} syntax, but not as a CSS style.

This works fine:

```
Total Staked {{ gems }}/{{ size }} ({{
              Math.round((gems / size) * 100)
            }}%)
```

This looks like this when rendered: **Total Staked 200/350 (57%)**

I would like to put that calculated percentage (57%) into css inline style like this:

```
<div class="bg-black h-2 rounded-md text-white" style="width: 57%"></div>
```

where the width: 57% is populated dynamically.

I am using Vue 3 with Tailwind CSS

Here is a Codepen: https://codepen.io/johnwinsor/pen/RwxvdZZ

Thank you!

Comment: You may use HTML5 `<progress value="" max="">` tag. This [article](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) may help you to style progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create computed property and bind your style:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      gems: 300,
      size: 350
    };
  },
  computed: {
    wid() {
      return Math.round((this.gems / this.size) * 100)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" integrity="sha512-wnea99uKIC3TJF7v4eKk4Y+lMz2Mklv18+r4na2Gn1abDRPPOeef95xTzdwGD9e6zXJBteMIhZ1+68QC5byJZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="app">
  <div>
<!--     Thermometer -->
    <div class="w-2/3 h-2 pl-5 pr-5 m-auto">
        <div class="w-full h-2 mt-6 mb-2 bg-red-500 rounded-md">
           <div class="bg-black h-2 rounded-md text-white" :style="`width: ${wid}%`"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--     Caption -->
    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center align-center pb-5">
      <p class="text-red-600">
        Total Staked {{ gems }}/{{ size }} ({{ wid }}%)
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```